# AWS Quicksight Embedded URL Pass Parameters Server Side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I want to integrate QuickSight Dashboard in my application. I already implemented the getEmbedUrl() function and also a UI. However I need to pass it extra parameters to filter from the dashboard itself. I only found a solution client side like this

```
async function embedDashboard(url, container) {
      const context = await createEmbeddingContext();
      const frameOptions = {
        url,
        container,
        height: "800px",
        iframeResizeOnSheetChange: true,
        footerPaddingEnabled: false,
        printEnabled: true,
        width: "100%",
        onChange: (changeEvent, metadata) => {
          switch (changeEvent.eventName) {
            case "FRAME_MOUNTED": {
              console.log("Do something when the experience frame is mounted.");
              break;
            }
            case "FRAME_LOADED": {
              console.log("Do something when the experience frame is loaded.");
              break;
            }
          }
        },
      };
      const contentOptions = {
        parameters: [
          {
            Name: "customerId",
            Values: [customerId],
          },
        ],
```

For security issues, is there a way to do this server side? When I am fetching the URL?

```
quicksightClient.getDashboardEmbedUrl({
            'AwsAccountId': 
            'DashboardId': 
            'AdditionalDashboardIds': [],
            'Namespace': 'default',
            'IdentityType': 'IAM',
            'SessionLifetimeInMinutes': 100,
            'UndoRedoDisabled': false,
            'ResetDisabled': true})
```

Somewhere here?

Answer (score 0):

After generating the embed url in your backend service, you can append the parameters as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-in-a-url.html

I did not find a way to already pass parameters in the `GenerateEmbedUrlForRegisteredUserCommand` method of the Javascript SDK though.